# How can I force gcloud cli to not monitor certain directories when running dev_appserver.py?

Tags: reactjs, go, gcloud

I'm developing an app locally using Go and React with a project structure that looks somewhat like this:

```
/reactApp 
   /main.go
   /api 
   /reactUI
```

While I am developing locally I am using the gcloud cli tool to run the Go code, and I'm using Node to run the UI. I need to handle CORS of course, but otherwise this works fairly well. The problem is there are too many files in the /reactUI directory for the gcloud cli tool to monitor them all. This means I need to manually start and stop the server every time I make a change to the Go source code.

The reactUI directory was created using the 'npx create-react-app' command. Since I'm running the react part of this app locally using node (and that handles file monitoring and auto-updating just fine), how can I get the gcloud tool to ignore the reactUI directory?

Basically I just want the gcloud tool to monitor the API part of the app, and not the UI part. If I make a change to the API part of the app the gcloud local server should automatically recompile and restart.

Comment: Is moving `reactUI` component outside the project directory an option ? React has its own runtime so, it doesn't need go code on the same directory.

Comment: For most of the reactUI contents, yes. However the 'build' directory inside the 'reactUI' directory must stay in place. I am using go to serve the index.html file and the css and js files created by react native. Maybe there is a way to set this up in the React build settings? I will have to look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35895450 fixed the development server is supposed to not monitor changes in the files/directories matching the patterns specified in the [`skip_files`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#skip_files) section of the app/service's `.yaml` file.

So you can try to add a `skip_files` section to the go app's `.yaml` file specifying  the patterns for the files/directories you want ignored. Be careful to also add the default patterns (otherwise you'd lose them).

Comment: To help anyone with this specific issue, simply add the following to your app.yaml file: skip_files:
- ^node_modules(/.*)? 
- .*node_modules